# Combining two strings in a certain order

Tags: php

How to combine strings $a and $b so that 1st digit of $a is placed as 2nd character of $b, 2nd digit as 4th character of $b, 3rd digit as 7th character of $b and 4th digit as 11th character of $b.

So lets say $a = 1234
and $b = abcdefghijklmnop

I want to get this: a1b2cd3efg4hijklmnop

Is there a function to combine it like this + reverse back if needed?

Comment: No - you'd have to write functions to do that.

Comment: Why _would_ there be a built-in function for this? It seems very specific. What would you use this for? Just curious.

Comment: do you want to continue that format the merge or its fixed that you will only have length 4 of first string? Yo can iterate through the first string and use substr_replace() method to replace into second string by using the position of the character. You need to replace with logical character plus digit of first string.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using multiple array and using `array_splice()` to insert the value at a certain point.

```
$logicArr = [1,3,6,10]; //Logic Array = Each position of array
$arrOne = [1,2,3,4]; //Values to add to the array
$arrTwo = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g', 'h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p']; //Data Array

foreach ($arrOne as $k=>$v) {

    array_splice($arrTwo, $logicArr[$k], 0, $v); //Insert value from $arrOne at position $logicArr[$k] using iteration of Foreach loop.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through each character in `$b` and only insert the next character from `$a` whenever you reach the desired position:

```
function mix($a, $b)
{
    $a = str_split($a);
    $b = str_split($b);
    $mixed = '';

    $nextInsertPos = 1; // 2nd character
    $indexA = 0;

    foreach ($b as $indexB => $charB) {
        if ($indexB + $indexA == $nextInsertPos) {
            $mixed .= $a[$indexA++];
            $nextInsertPos = $nextInsertPos + ($indexA + 1);
        }
        $mixed .= $charB;
    }

    return $mixed;
}
```